# Does Switch(Select) Works between TRANSFORM And SELECT?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to add a `Switch` between a `Transform` and a `Select` But this throw the following error.

> Multi-level GROUP BY clause not allowed in subquery

Below is a sample of my SQL Query

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Rate*
SWITCH(Name = 'Name1',(SELECT sum(MktValue)/(select sum(MktValue) FROM Table2 WHERE Portefeuille IN ( 'Name1' , 'Name2') AND LaDate = #27/10/2021#) FROM Table2 WHERE Name IN ( 'Name1') AND LaDate = #27/10/2021#),Name = 'Name2',0.75,true,0)
SELECT Sector
FROM Table1
WHERE Name IN ( 'Name1' , 'Name2') AND LaDate = #27/10/2021#"
GROUP BY Sector
Pivot Name
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Please note that `Switch()` is used to calculate factor. ( MktValue / Sum(AllMktValue))

The below query works

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Rate * 0.33)
SELECT Sector
FROM Table1
WHERE Name IN ( 'Name1' , 'Name2') AND LaDate = #27/10/2021#"
GROUP BY Sector
Pivot Name
```

Since the above query is working fine I assume my issue come from the `SWITCH`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```sql
TRANSFORM SUM(Rate * SWITCH(
    Name = 'Name1',
    (SELECT Sum(MktValue) FROM Table2 WHERE Name IN ('Name1') AND LaDate = #2021/10/27#) / 
    (SELECT Sum(MktValue) FROM Table2 WHERE Portefeuille IN ('Name1','Name2') AND LaDate = #2021/10/27#),
    Name = 'Name2', 0.75,
    True, 0)
```